# Colocar varios marker personalizados (lista) en google maps static

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

Muy buenos dias comunidad, tengo la siguiente situacion:
Esto trabajando con google maps js y stactis, tengo una lista de markers personalizados(custom markers), que al hacer clic sobre uno de ellos y luego clic en el mapa js funciona perfecto, al hacer clic en otro marker personalizado y clic en el mapa lo agrega perfecto y veo los dos markers personalizados, esto en el google maps javascript api, pero la cosa cambia en el mapa static(tipo imagen)hasta ahora consigo lo siguiente del js a stactic: colocar labels personalizados, color personalizado; pero al querer que me agregue los markers personalizados al static en la url me muestra ese espacio "undefined" y se rompe el string de estatic. Quizas es una tonteria pero estoy algo ofuscado. Si se dan cuenta tengo dos `<div>`, uno para el mapa js (map) y uno para el mapa imagen(staticmap)

el html es algo asi:

```
    <!-- creando columnas 2 con mapa-->
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight" id="map"></div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight" id="staticmap">
      <h2>Static map</h2> 
    </div>
  </div>
          <td><img src="assets/icons/MapMarker_Flag1_Right_Red.png" alt="" onclick="selectIcon(this);" width="50" id="icon1"></td>
          &nbsp;
          <td><img src="assets/icons/MapMarker_Flag1_Right_Green.png" alt="" onclick="selectIcon(this);" width="50" id="icon2"></td>
          &nbsp
          <td><img src="assets/icons/MapMarker_Flag1_Right_Blue.png" alt="" onclick="selectIcon(this);" width="50" id="icon3"></td>
          &nbsp
          <td><img src="assets/icons/MapMarker_Flag1_Right_Azure.png" alt="" onclick="selectIcon(this);" width="50" id="icon4"></td>
          &nbsp;
          <td><img src="assets/icons/MapMarker_Flag1_Right_Chartreuse.png" alt="" onclick="selectIcon(this);" width="50" id="icon5"></td>
          &nbsp;
```

y el segmento de codigo del static es algo asi:

```
function addLatLng(point) {
        function selectIcon(icon) {
            img = icon.id;
            newIconS = document.getElementById(img).src;
            document.getElementById('selectIcon').src = newIconS;
            //console.log('el id es: '+img);
            //console.log('la url es: ' + newIconS);
            return newIconS;
        }; 

        label= labelst[labelIndext++ % labelst.length],
        clickpoint = point.latLng;
        var coordsaved = text6 +'icon:'+newIconS+'%7C'+ 'label:'+label+ '%7C'+point.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)+','+point.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)+'';
        if (counter == 0) {
            coordstring = coordsaved;
            counter = 1;
        } else {
            coordstring = coordstring + coordsaved;
        }
        tobrowser();
    }
```

esa variable `newIconS` la tengo declarada global y la funcion `function selectIcon(icon)` funciona perfecto para el mapa js, pero al insertarla aqui ni siquiera la llama ._., quizas porque ya la estoy usando en la funcion global?

Comment: imagen: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z4u46IOctMnZG8AYtzZ5A0_nc9H_kv9-

Comment: realice una prueba agregando un icono predefinido y entonces no muestra las labels, tambien la url del icono tiene que ser remota no me toma local, mas sino defino ningun icono sino que el tome el por defecto si muestra las labels ._.